# DeliciousSoda: A simple parser for robots.txt files

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

*This is my first big project that I've decided to release publically. It's available on my [Github](https://github.com/Linnydude3347/delicioussoda), and through `pip3`: `pip3 install delicioussoda`.*

This is a simple parser for robots.txt files for a website. And yes, the name "DeliciousSoda" is a play off of "BeautifulSoup".

As I intended to keep developing and adding more features to this module, I would really appreciate some feedback on every part of my code. Here are a couple main things:

- How is my handling of ensuring the url is valid, and that the site has a robots.txt file?
- How is my use of custom exceptions?
- I've decided to use `__` before some methods only used within the class. I also do this for any variables. Is this unnecessary?
- `get_allowed` and `get_disallowed` both seem unnecessarily complicated. I feel like I can accomplish the same thing with less code. Is this possible?
- How is my example usage? I use this to test the module without writing another file. Should I implement something like [`unittest`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.html)?

Appreciate any and all feedback provided. Thank you in advance.

```
"""
DeliciousSoda
~~~~~~~~~~~~~

DeliciousSoda is a webscraper for robots.txt files. Basic usage:

>>> from delicioussoda import DeliciousSoda
>>> s = DeliciousSoda('https://www.google.com')
>>> s.get_allowed()
['Allow: /search/about', 'Allow: /search/static', ...]

:copyright: (c) 2019 by Ben Antonellis.
:license: MIT, see LICENSE for more details. 

"""

__all__ = [
    "DeliciousSoda"
]

# Standard Library Imports
import os
from typing import List, Dict, Union
import urllib.request
from urllib.error import HTTPError

# Install Requires
import requests
from requests.exceptions import SSLError

class DeliciousSoda():
    """
    A custom robots.txt parser. Assumes ' User-agent: * '.
    """

    def __init__(self, url=None):
        self.__url = url
        self.__robots_file = None

        if self.__url is not None:
            self.set_url(url)
            self.__validate_url()
            self.__content = self.__download_robots()

    def __str__(self) -> str:
        return f"DeliciousSoda Parsing: {self.__url}"

    def set_url(self, url: str) -> None:
        """
        Sets DeliciousSoda to retrieve robots.txt from this url.
        :param url -> str: Url
        :return: None
        """
        if not url.endswith("robots.txt"):
            if url.endswith("/"):
                self.__url = f"{url}robots.txt"
            else:
                self.__url = f"{url}/robots.txt"
        else:
            self.__url = url
        self.__content = self.__download_robots()

    def __validate_url(self) -> None:
        """
        Checks current url's validity.
        :return: None
        """
        try:
            response = requests.get(self.__url, timeout=5)
        except SSLError:
            raise InvalidUrlException("\n\nInvalidUrlException: Invalid Url.\n")

    def __download_robots(self) -> List[str]:
        """
        Downloads robots.txt file from url, loads the content from it, and returns a list of lines in the file.
        :return List[str]: Lines in the file
        """
        if self.__url is not None:
            # Ensure url is valid #
            self.__validate_url()

            # Ensure file exists #
            try:
                self.__robots_file, _ = urllib.request.urlretrieve(self.__url, filename="page.html")
            except HTTPError as error:
                if error.code == 404:
                    raise InvalidUrlException(f"\n\nInvalidUrlException: Site does not have a robots.txt file.\n")

            # Load lines and return list #
            with open(self.__robots_file, "r") as file:
                content = [line for line in file]

            # Remove file and return lines #
            os.remove(self.__robots_file)
            return content

        raise InvalidUrlException("\n\nInvalidUrlException: Invalid Url.\n")

    def get_sitemap(self) -> Union[str, None]:
        """
        Returns the sitemap of the webiste, None if it doesn't exist.
        :return Union[str, None]: Either the sitemap of robots.txt, or None
        """
        for line in self.__content:
            if line.startswith("Sitemap:"):
                return line[9:].rstrip()
        return None

    def get_allowed(self) -> List[str]:
        """
        Gets all allowed directories for the url.

        :return List[str]: Allowed directories
        """
        if self.__url is not None:
            allowed = []
            for line in self.__content:
                if line == "\n":
                    break
                if line.startswith("Allow:"):
                    allowed.append(line.rstrip()[7:])
            return allowed
        raise InvalidUrlException("\n\nInvalidUrlException: Invalid Url.\n")

    def get_disallowed(self) -> List[str]:
        """
        Gets all disallowed directories for the url.
        :return List[str]: Disallowed directories
        """
        if self.__url is not None:
            disallowed = []
            for line in self.__content:
                if line == "\n":
                    break
                if line.startswith("Disallow:"): 
                    disallowed.append(line.rstrip()[10:])
            return disallowed
        raise InvalidUrlException("\n\nInvalidUrlException: Invalid Url.\n")

    def get_all(self) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
        """
        Returns a dict of both allowed and disallowed directories under User-agent: *.
        :return Dict[str, List[str]]: Dictionary of allowed and disallowed directories under User-agent: *
        """
        if self.__url is not None:
            return {
                "Allow": self.get_allowed(),
                "Disallow": self.get_disallowed()
            }
        raise InvalidUrlException("\n\nInvalidUrlException: Invalid Url.\n")

class InvalidUrlException(Exception):
    """ Url passed to DeliciousSoda object is `Invalid`. """
    pass

# Example Usage

if __name__ == "__main__":
    __robot = DeliciousSoda("https://www.google.com")
    __sitemap = __robot.get_sitemap()
    __allowed = __robot.get_allowed()
    __disallowed = __robot.get_disallowed()
    __both = __robot.get_all()  

    # print(__robot)
    # print(__sitemap)
    # print(__allowed)
    # print(__disallowed)
    # print(__both)
```

Comment: What documentation generator are you using?

Comment: @Peilonrayz None, I write all of the documentation myself.

Comment: A document generator doesn't generate docstrings. It generates websites _from your docstrings_.

Comment: Write programs that do one thing well. Does it really need to download the file, or just parse it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

- I tried using `__` once and found it to produce more problems than it's worth. Take:

  ```
  def __foo():
      return 'foo'


  class Bar:
      def __init__(self):
          self.__baz = __foo()


  Bar()
  ```

  ```
  NameError: name '_Bar__foo' is not defined
  ```

  I'd suggest you follow PEP 8 and only use it for classes that *will be subclassed* and where you *need* to prevent name collisions. `__robot` in global scope isn't following the advice in [PEP 8's Naming Conventions - Method Names and Instance Variables](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#method-names-and-instance-variables)

  > Python mangles these names with the class name: if class Foo has an attribute named `__a`, it cannot be accessed by `Foo.__a`. (An insistent user could still gain access by calling `Foo._Foo__a`.) Generally, double leading underscores should be used only to avoid name conflicts with attributes in classes designed to be subclassed.
  >
  > Note: there is some controversy about the use of __names (see below).
- Your docstrings aren't consistent, nor are they PEP 257 compliant.
  You should lint your code and use Sphinx.
- Your class seems to have a lot of noise in it because you've chosen to make it mutable. This is a poor design choice.
- You can `url.rstrip('/')` to remove the need for another `if` in `_set_url`.
- If `url` is passed to `DeliciousSoda` than you run `__download_robots` twice. This is a waste.
- Don't add `\n` to exceptions. If you really want to add this mutate the `InvalidUrlException`'s `__init__`. But seriously, please don't.
- Don't add the name of the exception to the exception message. Python does this automagically.
- If I were a consumer, I would prefer to be able to distinguish between the errors your program raises. You should raise different errors when there's an invalid URL or the site doesn't have a robots.
- `__download_robots` shouldn't be validating the URL. You should do that when you set the URL. Furthermore if your class was immutable then you could ignore all of this. Including the `self.__url is not None` part.
- `__download_robots` seems overly engineered. You're downloading a file to your filesystem to then reading the *entire* file into memory. Clearly there's an unneeded step.
- You should make `set_url`, `__validate_url` and `__download_robots` become one single, `download_robots` function, not method. This function can also take an *args and **kwargs that delegates to `requests.get`.
- The rest of your code is how you parse the robots. At which point you may as well just make that a function and return a dictionary.

```
"""
:copyright: (c) 2019 by Ben Antonellis, Peilonrayz.
:license: CC BY-SA 4.0.
"""

from typing import List, Dict
import collections
import os

from requests.exceptions import SSLError
import requests


def _normalize_robots_url(url: str) -> str:
    url = url.rstrip('/')
    if not url.endswith('robots.txt'):
        url += "/robots.txt"
    return url


def _download_robots(url: str, *args, **kwargs) -> str:
    url = _normalize_robots_url(url)
    try:
        r = requests.get(url, *args, **kwargs)
    except SSLError:
        raise InvalidUrlException("Invalid Url")
    r.raise_for_status()
    return r.text


def _parse_robots(robots: str) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
    info: Dict[str, List[str]] = collections.defaultdict(list)
    for line in robots.split('\n'):
        name, value, *_ = *line.split(': ', 1), None
        if name and not name.startswith('#'):
            info[name].append(value)
    return info


def delicious_soda(url: str, *args, **kwargs) -> Dict[str, List[str]]:
    robots = _download_robots(url, *args, **kwargs)
    return _parse_robots(robots)


class InvalidUrlException(Exception):
    """ Url passed to DeliciousSoda object is `Invalid`. """
    pass


# Example Usage
if __name__ == "__main__":
    robots = delicious_soda("https://www.google.com")
    print(robots.keys())
    print(robots['Sitemap'])
    print(robots['User-agent'])
    print(robots['Allow'])
    print(robots['Disallow'])
```

---

Given the above functions I still have some concerns.

1. I personally consider calling `_normalize_robots_url` inside `_download_robots` an anti-pattern. The *normalizing in fetch* anti-pattern if you will.

   You should normalize your data before you perform the fetch. If I'm asking for `example.com/robots-new.txt` then I should have a pretty good reason to. Your 'help' of then appending `/robots.txt` to the end of *my valid url* has caused me needless problems.

   I recommend exposing `_normalize_robots_url` as a function that people can call *if* they want that behavior.
2. I also find `delicious_soda` to be an anti-pattern. The *fetch and parse* anti-pattern if you will.

   This is bad as it needlessly locks users into one usage. What if I want to cache the fetch, what if I need to stream it, what if I need to handle user authentication. What if I need to do something with the fetch *you can't think of*? At that point I can't use your library.

   IMO a library provider always needs to provide fetching and parsing as two separate entities. The cost to most users is having to do `parse(fetch())`. If you want to expose a helper function too, that's cool, but not exposing both as separate things is just bad.
3. The function `_parse_robots` seems like the best part of the library. Whilst the way you implemented it in `DeliciousSoda` isn't great. It's the best part of the library.

   But I don't think it's great as a stand alone library, as I've implemented most of the features in a 7 line function, which I'd hope most Python programmers could mimic with ease.

In all currently the library is just a 7 line function - `_parse_robots`. I don't think `_download_robots` is great as part of the library. I'd elect to just use `requests` which is more powerful and I know it won't break when I enter valid urls.

I would suggest expanding on `_parse_robots` in a way that makes the library somewhat more usable. Say converting it into a class and adding a `DS.allowed_url` method.

Comment: You've given me a lot to think about and improve upon. Thank you.

Comment: When I read through the code I wondered why you kept "normalize", "fetch" and "parse" module privates. Further points expand on that and I'd add that, since `delicious_soda` is just an helper function, you can add a `normalize_url=True` parameter on top of moving the normalize call here.

Comment: @409_Conflict I think moving the normalize into the helper with that flag could be a pretty good solution too. +1 Yeah, I thought explicitly stating why removing that `_` makes such a big difference to the general design would help a lot (even though the anti-patterns are basically just instances of "no god-classes" and SRP).

Answer (score 7):

Disclaimer: Don't know Python nor PEP 8.

In `__download_robots(self)` you could reverse the `if` condition and return early which saves one level of indentation.

```
if self.__url is None:
    raise InvalidUrlException("\n\nInvalidUrlException: Invalid Url.\n")  

..the remaining code
```

this applies to `get_allowed(self)`, `get_disallowed(self)` and `get_all(self)` as well.

In the `except` block of `__download_robots(self)` you only check for `if error.code == 404:` shouldn't you check for other error codes, like `401 Unauthorized` as well?

---

`get_disallowed(self)` and `get_allowed(self)` could be combined in one method in which you pass a `search_phrase` containing either `Allow:` or `Disallow:` and using the `len(search_phrase) + 1` as the array-index.